# RegEx for matching specific log patterns

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

Have spending a little time on this, but regex it's a word and it's very difficult to sort out all the possibilities, this is the text:

```
iPhone 5s (B6780382-ADBC-4F92-B1CA-52111A5A6FBE) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6 (FDA15891-2487-4C9E-A7F2-0E476C652E1D) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6 Plus (58D4FC86-8E22-4995-816D-BC8799AE1220) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6s (AE9BCF92-4814-4ABD-A791-FA60E0919156) (Shutdown)
iPhone 6s Plus (5D431BB6-42AE-455D-8501-2227687D1A00) (Shutdown)
iPhone 7 (0211256D-308F-4210-807D-DAAD02CC8AD9) (Shutdown)
iPhone 7 Plus (872D5513-434C-4618-9350-A2AB77B04459) (Shutdown)
iPhone 8 (74F7E423-1D17-475E-B18B-0FAAFC19DD0F) (Shutdown)
iPhone 8 Plus (DB424FB3-6D34-4FE9-82AD-E50F439A47AD) (Shutdown)
iPhone SE (ECF43B3D-38E1-4A37-8B07-C3CB72B14AE0) (Shutdown)
iPhone X (40D45896-6325-4BB6-99D2-420E3472B68E) (Shutdown)
iPhone Xs (5AAFEA8B-CE48-4DBE-9BAD-F9A714FAB4BA) (Shutdown)
iPhone Xs Max (29946005-C6FF-4E77-98C4-A104917A9FD9) (Shutdown)
iPhone Xʀ (205A5924-472E-4B83-AB7D-5FA56D93DC01) (Shutdown)
iPad Air (3rd generation) (54CE7050-9D80-4000-87AC-D1717C3F5890) (Shutdown)
iPad Air (83D98641-4FE8-476A-991E-14C0BF687DC6) (Shutdown)
iPad Air 2 (E6951B0F-2DD3-4361-8469-BA319D1FACA9) (Shutdown)
iPad (5th generation) (CB7A9551-9B29-4999-82A0-872C3700C316) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (98FEC483-DC9B-4092-896E-CB9E8F165E51) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (DD14F482-E456-4E6D-A044-C72818A7C52D) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) (8C8364BA-A85D-4B3D-AD30-B179CA7F4541) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (AA6DEE43-167D-42A4-9399-4727651BDAC7) (Shutdown)
iPad (6th generation) (040A1950-770F-4DB0-BC0A-91237C23AAC6) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (07D97297-2E42-4FE8-B105-3245737D0CA3) (Shutdown)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (692172E8-2AFB-465A-AC0D-4109AF1679B5) (Shutdown)
```

So, for me have the names that is already fixed is ok, like "iPhone" or "iPad", but it's not only this, this is what I have done so far:

Regex:

```
((iPhone)|(iPad Air)|(iPad Pro)|(iPad))(\s)(\d{1}|\w{2}|\w{1}|\s)(\s)(\w{4}\s|\()
```

I need to get each item per line like this:

```
iPad Pro (11-inch) (07D97297-2E42-4FE8-B105-3245737D0CA3) (Shutdown)
```

And possible split by group, like name, after the unique key and at the end the status "shutdown"

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general approach

`(?im)^[^\S\r\n]*([^()\r\n]+?)[^\S\r\n]*(?:(\(.*?\)))?[^\S\r\n]*\(([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)*)\)[^\S\r\n]*(\(.*?\))`

https://regex101.com/r/PZlZap/1

Explained

```
 (?im)
 ^  
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 (                             # (1 start), Product
      [^()\r\n]+? 
 )                             # (1 end)
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 (?:
      (                             # (2 start), Optional Product description
           \( 
           .*? 
           \) 
      )                             # (2 end)
 )?
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 \( 
 (                             # (3 start), Product key
      [a-f0-9]+ 
      (?: - [a-f0-9]+ )*
 )                             # (3 end)
 \) 
 [^\S\r\n]* 
 (                             # (4 start), Shutdown
      \( 
      .*? 
      \) 
 )                             # (4 end)
```